# How to use bootstrap js together with jquery-ui?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

In bootstrap doc is mentioned to include its js I have to use:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I think here I already called jquery.js? or this slim is something else?

When I I want to use jquery-ui

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "input" ).checkboxradio({
      icon: false
    });
  } );
  </script>
```

It says checkboxradio is not a function. I added this too as mentioned jquery-ui doc:

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
```

but still not working. what mistake I did?

EDIT: I believe there is a conflict between bootstrap js and jQuery-ui. I know there is a jQuery function that tells jQuery that this function is not for you and this way conflicting is avoided. I don't remember that function. Can someone help?

Comment: jQuery ui is not jQuery. Where do you include jQuery ui?

Comment: In source code I showed above I have `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

Comment: Once to page is loaded, check your console to ensure that jQuery UI loaded properly. It's possible it conflicted with another library or another namespace that has the same function name. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Actually I did use console and it says function not found. There should be a conflict. How to fix it? I believe jquery has a command to avoid conflicts. But how is it?

Comment: I edited original post above.